# Can't Render Data From API in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to render data from API, but when i want to view the data in render can't appear here my code, i got my error the data soal_id is undefined. How to make appear the data with the true way? when i try to show the another data this is same doesn't appear and showing error.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
// import { cos } from 'react-native-reanimated';

export default class QuizTes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        soal : [],
        index:0,
    };
  }
  
  getSoal =()=>{
      fetch('http://unnamed48.ccug.gunadarma.ac.id:9091/api/user/soal',{
          method:'post',
          headers:{
              'Accept' : 'application/json',
              'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            token:"4266ae6eddc02afa38fa39477c22ab5f",
            studi:"penalaran umum"
          })
      }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(getData =>{
            // console.log(getData)
            if(getData){
                this.setState({
                    soal : getData.data
                })
            }
        }).catch(error =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.getSoal()
  }

  nextSoal = ()=>{
    this.setState({index:(this.state.index + 1) % this.state.soal.length})
}

prevSoal = ()=>{
    this.setState({index:(this.state.index - 1) % this.state.soal.length})
}

  render() {
    const item = this.state.soal[this.state.index]
    // var items = JSON.parse(item)
    // console.log(items)
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> QuizTes </Text>
        <Text> {JSON.stringify(item).soal_id}/20 </Text>
        {/* <Text> {item.soal_pertanyaan} </Text> */}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(item).soal_id` ? is it correct?

Comment: i got error when i use that code. When i use **item.soal_id** i got the same error the soal_id is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `JSON.stringify` in your case. In the render method, just make a  check on `item` and then render

**Like this**

```js
<Text> {item && item.soal_id}/20 </Text>
```

Comment: wow that's amazing, the value is showing now, thank you for helping. I'm sorry for my bad english.